# likely for someone to V

Tags: adjectives, complementation

Are the following uses of "likely for" okay? If one is okay but the other is not, please explain why:

> a. There are some things you can do to make it more likely for you to catch their attention.

> b. It is more likely for you to catch their attention if you take these steps.

Comment: "Likely for you to" is not very idiomatic.  In the opinion of this US English speaker, something more idiomatic would be **...more likely that you will...**

Comment: @stangdon "likely for someone to V" is used in dictionary definitions. E.g. "There are things you can do to stack the odds in your favor. [=to make it more likely for you to win, succeed, etc.]"  https://learnersdictionary.com/definition/stack

Answer (score 1):

The sentences are grammatically correct, but "It is likely for you..." is rather verbose, and is generally only used to express an indirect consequence of an action, for example creating an environment where something might happen.

> If you visit a rough area of town, it is likely that you will be mugged. - *indirect consequence*
> If you insult the doorman at a club, you are likely to get a beating. -*direct consequence*

Your two sentences suggest that, if you take certain steps, the direct consequence is that you are more likely to be noticed. The second sentence is the easiest to suggest a direct consequence:

> **You** are more likely to catch their attention if you take these steps.

For your first sentence, this does suggest some indirection, but I feel that it would read better using **that you will** rather than **for you to**. This [NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=likely%20that%20you%20will%20be%2C%20likely%20for%20you%20to%20be&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clikely%20that%20you%20will%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clikely%20for%20you%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0) supports my opinion.

> There are some things you can do to make it more likely **that you will** catch their attention.

Comment: What do you mean by "passive voice" There's nothing passive in the OP sentenves.

Comment: You using a dummy subject **is**, then using the preposition **for** to attach the real subject.  This is similar to passive voice, where you eliminate the subject and attach it as an agent using the preposition **by**.

Comment: "likely for someone to V" is used in dictionary definitions. E.g. "There are things you can do to stack the odds in your favor. [=to make it more likely for you to win, succeed, etc.]"  Is this definitionese?

Comment: https://learnersdictionary.com/definition/stack

Comment: "used in dictionary definitions"... I bet this is the only definition that uses it, and the situation is unusual. They are using **you** to mean **anybody**, as in the maxim "you can't beat the system". and it would sound strange to say "to make yourself more likely to win" where **yourself** is suppose to mean **anybodyself**.

Comment: What does the use of "you" to mean "anybody" have to do with "likely for someone to V"? Also, that is not the only definition that uses "likely for.":The definition of "conducive" in Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary has "making it easy, possible or likely for sth to happen"

Comment: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/conducive?q=conducive

Comment: "conducive" is definitely indirect: you are creating an environment where something is more likely to happen: the "making it likely" locution is probably more accurate. Your sentences are not indirect: you are doing something that will directly get you noticed.

Comment: What does the "indirect vs. direct"  distinction have to do with "llikely for sb. to V"? I don't see the connection. Also, consider this sentence: "There is also some evidence that distraction can make it more likely for you to blame others for their misfortune."

Comment: "Filling up a bowl with nuts, fruits, or prepared vegetables and putting it where you can grab it fast makes it easier and more likely for you to grab something healthy to snack on in a pinch than a bag of chips or another unhealthy snack option."